# Swapping values in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem:

> Write a function that takes an array as an argument and return an array with the first and last values swapped. The array will have a minimum length of 2 (ex. [1,5,10,-2] should return [-2,5,10,1]).

My code:

```
function test(arr) {
    // arr is 1, 2, 3, 4
    var first = arr[0];
    var last = arr[arr.length - 1];
    console.log(first);
    console.log(last);
    // output should be 4, 2, 3, 1
}

test([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic? Or are you asking for a general check to make sure everything is coded as well as possible?

Comment: Hey Nathan, just a general check. What happens is that the code comes out as undefined instead of printing the array swapped.

Comment: You are missing the actual solution of your problem. Try by yourself at least something and check whether it works *before* posting to SO.

Comment: From the problem description: "... return an array ..." - Your function never returns anything (the keyword `return` isn't in that code anywhere), so you probably should start with that...

Comment: Well, it looks like you have the answer, you have both the first and the last values, just change the values in the array and return it. `arr['first']=last; arr['last']=first;return arr;`

Comment: @Aguardientico OP is close to the solution, I think we should let him figure it out for himself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually mutate the array and return it:

```
function test(arr) {
  var first = arr[0];
  var last = arr[arr.length - 1];

  arr[0] = last;
  arr[arr.length - 1] = first;

  return arr;
}
```